# How to configure the jetty maven plugin to allow to deploy 2 apps under the same port?

Tags: maven-jetty-plugin

I’ am starting to develop 2 web apps with maven&jetty.

Does somebody know how to configure the jetty maven plugin to allow to deploy the 2 apps under the same port?

When I do the mvn jetty:run for the second app I get the expected error:

*Address already in use: bind*

I want to be able to hit http://localhost:8080/appA and http://localhost:8080/appB

Actually, this is what I have in the pom.xml for boths appA and appB:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do that. The best option for you will be to have an standalone jetty (or tomcat) server and deploy, redeploy and undeploy your apps directly on that server.

Check this Maven plugin that has that funcionality for almost all J2EE containers: Geronimo, Glassfish, JBoss, Jetty, Jonas, Resin, Tomcat and Weblogic.

http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin